# Scrapyd error when trying to schedule a job

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

When I try yo schedule a job after I have deployed a project I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapyd/webservice.py", line 18, in render
    return JsonResource.render(self, txrequest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/txweb.py", line 10, in render
    r = resource.Resource.render(self, txrequest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/resource.py", line 250, in render
    return m(request)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapyd/webservice.py", line 37, in render_POST
    self.root.scheduler.schedule(project, spider, **args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapyd/scheduler.py", line 16, in schedule
    q.add(spider_name, **spider_args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapyd/spiderqueue.py", line 18, in add
    self.q.put(d, priority)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapyd/sqlite.py", line 103, in put
    self.conn.execute(q, args)
OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
```

If after deploying the project I go and restart scrapyd and after schedule a job there is no problems with it and works fine. But to be honest I do not see the point of going and restarting scrapyd everytime I deploy... does not make sense.

I have checked the DB folder and there is a crawling_project.db file with root:root ownsership this could be causing the issue??